# Checkbox Change: update html with current checked elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have a series of `input[checkbox]` elements and when a checkbox is checked I grab it's parent's html.

In the snippet I'm going through each element individually (like if #apples is checked I set it's checked attribute to true and grab it's parent's html)

However I don't like going through and checking each element individually as seen here...

```
if ( $("#apples").is(":checked") ) {
  $("#apples").attr("checked", true);
} else {
  $("#apples").attr("checked", false);
}
if ( $("#oranges").is(":checked") ) {
  $("#oranges").attr("checked", true);
} else {
  $("#oranges").attr("checked", false);
}
if ( $("#grapes").is(":checked") ) {
  $("#grapes").attr("checked", true);
} else {
  $("#grapes").attr("checked", false);
}
```

Does anyone know if there's an easier way to do this?

```js
function checkCheckedHTML() {
  if ( $(".check").is(":checked") || !$(".check").is(":checked") ) {
    if ( $("#apples").is(":checked") ) {
      $("#apples").attr("checked", true);
    } else {
      $("#apples").attr("checked", false);
    }
    if ( $("#oranges").is(":checked") ) {
      $("#oranges").attr("checked", true);
    } else {
      $("#oranges").attr("checked", false);
    }
    if ( $("#grapes").is(":checked") ) {
      $("#grapes").attr("checked", true);
    } else {
      $("#grapes").attr("checked", false);
    }

    $(".wrapper").val( $(".container").html() );
    console.log("Checked: update html with current checked elements");
  }
}

$(".check").on("click change", function() {
  checkCheckedHTML();
});
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 600px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <input type="checkbox" class="check" id="apples"> 
  <label for="apples">apples</label>
  
  <input type="checkbox" class="check" id="oranges"> 
  <label for="oranges">oranges</label>
  
  <input type="checkbox" class="check" id="grapes"> 
  <label for="grapes">grapes</label>
</div>

<textarea class="wrapper"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to update the checked attribute of element which has been changed, you can access it's object by using `this` inside the change event callback

```js
$(".check").on("change", function() {
  $(this).attr('checked',this.checked);
  // updating checked attribute of change event occurred element, this.checked returns current state
  $(".wrapper").val( $(".container").html());
  // updating the value of textarea
});
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 600px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <input type="checkbox" class="check" id="apples"> 
  <label for="apples">apples</label>
  
  <input type="checkbox" class="check" id="oranges"> 
  <label for="oranges">oranges</label>
  
  <input type="checkbox" class="check" id="grapes"> 
  <label for="grapes">grapes</label>
</div>

<textarea class="wrapper"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".check").on("click change", function() {
   if ( $(".check").is(":checked")){
       $(this).attr("checked",true);  
   } else {
            $(this).attr("checked",false);  
   }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/y37L78pn/

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could do this...if I understood you correctly:-

```
$(".check").on("click change", function() {

  if ( $(this).is(":checked") ) $(this).attr("checked", true);
  else $(this).attr("checked", false);

  $(".wrapper").val( $(".container").html() );
    console.log("Checked: update html with current checked elements");
});
```

Check out the fiddle for this: https://jsfiddle.net/kfrjzwmh/